# Posting hardcoded razor string with @Html?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda

I am doing this, and it works very well to store into database.

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Messages.UserName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Messages.UserName)
```

But I also want to post:

```
string userIP = //...
```

into

```
model.Messages.UserIP
```

Sorry for the stupid question but I've been searching for this way too long.

Comment: Why don't you put it on the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a hiddenField for UserIP:

```
 @Html.Hidden("value", "Messages.UserIP");
```

Comment: Great! Just a detail: @Html.Hidden("value", Messages.UserIP) was the correct syntax for me.

Comment: Don't forget to note this answer as the correct answer